# Symfony injecting Doctrine Entity Manager into a class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

So I added the entity manager as an argument:

```
$container->setDefinition('ldap.security.authentication.provider',
    new Definition('Client\IntranetBundle\LDAP\LDAPAuthenticationProvider', array(
        new Reference("ldap_user_provider"),
        new Reference("ldap_manager")
    )))
    ->addArgument("ldap.security.authentication.provider")
    ->addArgument("doctrine.orm.entity_manager");
```

But in my class, if I echo this argument, all I get is this string: secured_area

How can I get the actual entity manager?

This is the construct method:

```
public function __construct(LDAPUserProvider $userProvider, LDAPManagerInterface $ldapManager, $entityManager, $providerKey) {
    //var_dump($userProvider);
    //var_dump($ldapManager);
    //var_dump($entityManager);
    //var_dump($providerKey);
    $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
    $this->ldapManager = $ldapManager;
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    $this->providerKey = $providerKey;
}
```

var_dump of $entityManager is string(12) "secured_area"

and

var_dump of $providerKey is string(37) "ldap.security.authentication.provider"

Comment: Could you please poste also code of Client\IntranetBundle\LDAP\LDAPAuthenticationProvider ? It looks like there is $providerKey under variable that you echo.

Answer (score 0):

```
$container->setDefinition('ldap.security.authentication.provider',
new Definition('Client\IntranetBundle\LDAP\LDAPAuthenticationProvider', array(
    new Reference("ldap_user_provider"),
    new Reference("ldap_manager"),
    new Reference("doctrine.orm.entity_manager"),
    /* Here you should pass providerKey */
)))
```

This is how service could be defined but I suggest you to read http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html before creating custom authentication provider.

Comment: I tried this way too, but it does not work. I get the same results when I do a var_dump() :/.